# Show Y axis on right side of chart with jqPlot

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

I am using below code to show Y axis of jqPlot at right side but its only showing me at left side:

```
$.jqplot.config.enablePlugins = true;

        var test2 = readXML(posi);

        plot2 = $.jqplot('chart2', [test2], {
            series: [{ renderer: $.jqplot.OHLCRenderer, rendererOptions: { candleStick: true, wickColor: '282828',
                upBodyColor: '00C000', fillUpBody: true, downBodyColor: 'F81700',
                fillDownBody: true, lineWidth: 1.5, tickLength: true, background: 'C8C8C6',
                closeColor: '282828', openColor: '282828'
            }
            }, { xaxis: 'x2axis', yaxis: 'y2axis'}],
            axesDefaults: {
                tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
                tickOptions: {
                    angle: 30
                }
            },
            axes: {
                xaxis: {
                    renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer
                },
                x2axis: {
                    renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer
                },
                yaxis: {
                    autoscale: true
                },
                y2axis: {
                    autoscale: true
                }
            }
        });
```

Please tell me where I am where my mistake is.

I have got the code above from the reference: http://www.jqplot.com/tests/canvasAxisTests.php in this the third example is showing values of at right side. I am using candlestick chart of jqPlot.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the CSS file that comes with the jqplot. It defines the settings for the jqplot-yaxis, and so you can use that for setting the desired location.